# How to make Google Mobile Vision to continuously trying to auto focus?

Tags: android, android-camera, barcode-scanner, android-camera2, firebase-mlkit

I'm using ML Kit. I'm trying to achieve the behavior where my barcode scanner Android app keeps trying to focus the camera while I move when trying to find a barcode. You know, the typical "clear-blur" behavior that we get when trying to use our phone camera to take a photo.

What are the settings I should turn on?

Comment: What "google barcode api"?  There's none in Android.  If you're using an outside library, specify it.  We can't just guess.

Comment: It's Google Mobile Vision

Comment: did you find something?